# angular state.go with the same stateParams

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app where I use `$state.go('state_name', stateParams)`.

The button which triggers `state.go` event is always available at the page while url changes depending on `stateParams`.

Everything works perfect until I pass the same stateParams object to `$state.go`. In this case nothing happens at all. Looks like angular compares `stateParams` in url and `stateParams` object which I pass to `state.go` and does nothing as values are the same. I expect `$state.go` to perform the same action like it does when I pass state params object with values that do not match url.

I know that this can be solved with `$state.go('state_name', stateParams, {reload: true})` but in my case this is what I don't really need as it reloads some parts of my applications which I don't need to reload.

**Can anybody advise please how can I call `state.go` with the same `stateParams` object without reload: true so angular works as expected.**

Comment: ui-sref="whatever(variableEqualtoStateParams)" ?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help. same behaviour ((

Comment: adding  ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" ?

Comment: it works but it does reload which I don't need ((

Comment: So you want a link to the same state and params, that if you click it reloads the state? So if you click 10 times the same link, it reloads that state same as if you navigated from somewhere else?

Comment: exactly. please

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, here you have a code snippet that seems to do what you want. ie if you click in a link it will always go to that state, even if you are there with the same params:

```
myApp.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$state', function ($delegate) {
    // let's locally use 'state' name
    var state = $delegate;

    // let's extend this object with new function
    // 'baseGo', which in fact, will keep the reference
    // to the original 'go' function
    state.baseGo = state.go;

    // here comes our new 'go' decoration
    var go = function (to, params, options) {
      options = options || {};

      // only in case of missing 'reload'
      // append our explicit 'true'
      if (angular.isUndefined(options.reload)) {

          options.reload = true;
      }

      // return processing to the 'baseGo' - original
      this.baseGo(to, params, options);
    };

    // assign new 'go', right now decorating the old 'go'
    state.go = go;

    return $delegate;
  });
})
```